# Why am I getting weird crashes with Qt5 depending on how I create the application instance?

Tags: c++, qt5

Here is a reduced version of my code:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>


class MainView : public QMainWindow
{
    public:
        static MainView *Initialise(int argc, char **argv);

        int Run() { return qApp->exec(); }

    private:
        MainView() { }
        virtual ~MainView() { }

};


namespace
{
    QApplication *s_app      {nullptr};
    MainView     *s_instance {nullptr};
};


MainView *MainView::Initialise(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (nullptr == s_app) {
        s_app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    }

    if (nullptr == s_instance) {
        s_instance = dynamic_cast<MainView *>(new MainView());
    }

    return s_instance;
}


class Framework
{
    public:
        Framework() { }
        ~Framework() { }

        int Initialise(int argc, char **argv)
        {
            m_main_view = MainView::Initialise(argc, argv);

            return 0;
        }

        int Run()
        {
            m_main_view->show();
            return m_main_view->Run();
        }

    private:
        MainView *m_main_view;

};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Framework  framework;
    int        result = 0;

    // Weirdness here!!!!
    MainView::Initialise(argc, argv);  // Crashes even with this line.

    result = framework.Initialise(argc, argv);
    if (0 == result) {
        result = framework.Run();
    }

    return result;
}
```

This code crashes when showing the MainWindow instance. In my full version of this code, where MainView inherits from a virtual interface class (so as to allow me to decouple the view and substitute a command line interface or a test interface) it doesn't crash unless I comment out the code marked as "weirdness here".

In this code, if I replace:

```cpp
MainView::Initialise(argc, argv);  // Crashes even with this line.
```

with:

```cpp
if (nullptr == s_app) {
    s_app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
}
```

then it works fine and doesn't crash.

Essentially if the application is instantiated within `MainView::Initialise()`, whether called from `main()` or from `Framework::Initialise()` then the program crashes, but if I initialise the application in `main()` first then it doesn't crash.

I don't want my `main()` function to have any knowledge of the UI at all, if possible, even taking my virtual base class interface into account. There should be no need and it makes `main()` messier than necessary.

So why is this crashing and how do I stop it?

Comment: Can't reproduce (Linux, g++ 10.2.1, Qt 5.15.2).

Comment: My work colleague is getting the same crash with, similar code to the above, code that works for me. Ubuntu 18, g++ 9.3.0, Qt 5.9.5. Compiled with command `g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 test.cpp -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Core -o test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between your invocation of the `QApplication` constructor in `main()` and the invocation in `MainView::Initialise()`.

The documentation for the QApplication constructor says:

> QApplication::**QApplication**(**int** &argc, **char** **argv)
>
> < ... >
>
> **Note:** argc and argv might be changed as Qt removes command line arguments that it recognizes.

So when invoking the constructor in `MainView::Initialise()`, you are actually passing a copy of the `argc` that came from main.  Presumably, Qt stores a reference to this internally somewhere, causing it to crash when the QApplication later dereferences it during the construction of the window.

If you change the signature of both `Initialise()` functions to take a reference to argc, the program works without crashing.

Comment: Wow! Just wow! I don't know if I am more surprised at the stupidity of Qt (storing a reference takes more room than an int on a 64 bit machine, and leads to problems like this), or your genius in spotting that.

Comment: I will try it and see what happens when I get the chance.